# How do I match an element with a name such as "data[title]" in a selector?

Tags: css

I have an element like this:

```
<input type="text" name="data[title]" />
```

Is it possible to match that input element based on it's name? This does not work:

```
input[name=data[title]] {}
```

I'm using the latest release of Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use quotes:

```
input[name="data[title]"] {}
```